# Prevent main content from being visible through navbar

Tags: html, css

Content using the `section` div class is visible beneath the `navbar`. This can be reproduced using the example below simply by scrolling down. How can I prevent this?

All help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```html
<title>test</title>
<style>
  
  body {margin:0;}

  .navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .navbar a {
     display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }

  .navbar a:hover {
    background: #ddd;
    color: black;
  }

  .section {
        position: relative;
    }
    .anchor {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        top: -50px;
        left: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
}

</style>

<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#item1">item1</a>
  <a href="#item2">item2</a>
  <a href="#item3">item3</a>
  <a href="#item4">item4</a>
  <a href="#item5">item5</a>
</div>

<div class="w3-row-padding" style="max-width: 50em;margin: auto; margin-top: 50px;">
  <div class="w3-full">

    <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

    <br>
  </div>
  <hr>

  <div class="w3-full section">
    <span id="lets" class="anchor"></span>
    <h1 style="margin-bottom:0px;">Test</h1>

    <p>This text will be covered</p>

  </div>


  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: for the fix add `z-index: 9;` to navbar .. any big number not necessarely 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `z-index` to place the navbar over your other content.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
  /*this line*/
}

.navbar a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
}

.anchor {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  top: -50px;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#item1">item1</a>
  <a href="#item2">item2</a>
  <a href="#item3">item3</a>
  <a href="#item4">item4</a>
  <a href="#item5">item5</a>
</div>

<div class="w3-row-padding" style="max-width: 50em;margin: auto; margin-top: 50px;">
  <div class="w3-full">

    <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

    <br>
  </div>
  <hr>

  <div class="w3-full section">
    <span id="lets" class="anchor"></span>
    <h1 style="margin-bottom:0px;">Test</h1>

    <p>This text will be covered</p>

  </div>


  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

  <p>Note: We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>
</div>
```